# Unable to create unique index for two belongs to associations

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, unique-constraint

I've got the following model:

```
class Access < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :site
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I've recently added the following validation:

```
validates :user_id, uniqueness: { scope: :site_id }
```

Now I wanted to additionally apply this validation on the database level. Therefore I created the following migration:

```
class AddUniqueIndexToAccesses < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_index :accesses, [:user_id, :site_id], unique: true
  end
end
```

However this migration is failing:

```
Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry 'XXXX-XXX' for key 'index_accesses_on_user_id_and_site_id': CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `index_accesses_on_user_id_and_site_id`  ON `accesses` (`user_id`, `site_id`)
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it? I just want to ensure the combination of the site and user for a access object is always unique.

Comment: just checked again

Comment: you're right there is some record with the same pair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything's correct, but you have some incorrect data in your database considering the unique index you want to create. Fix the data and you should be able to create the index. What I mean is that you have in the `accesses` table more than one pair `user_id` and `site_id` for some values.

Comment: I see, thanks a lot. How can I locate this incorrect data in order to fix it?

Comment: try something like `SELECT user_id, site_id, count(*) FROM acceses GROUP BY user_id, site_id HAVING count(*) > 1`